# Handle REST requests in golang GRPC server

Tags: rest, go, grpc, grpc-go

Is it possible for a GRPC server written in golang to also handle REST requests?

I've found the [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) which enables turning an existing proto schema into a rest endpoint but I don't think that suits my needs.

I've written a GRPC server but I need to also serve webhook requests from an external service (like Github or Stripe). I'm thinking of writing a second REST based server to accept these webhooks (and possibly translate/forward them to the GRPC server) but that seems like a code-smell.

Ideally, I'd like for my GRPC server to also be able to, for example, handle REST requests at an endpoint like `/webhook` or `/event` but I'm not sure if that's possible and if it is how to configure it.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://grpc.io/blog/coreos/ ?

Comment: Here the right way to implement it https://github.com/apssouza22/modern-api-management/tree/master/services/book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I asked my question before giving a large enough effort to resolve it my own. Here's an example of serving REST requests alongside GRPC requests

```golang
func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":6789")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    // here we register and HTTP server listening on port 6789
    // note that we do this in with gofunc so that the rest of this main function can execute - this probably isn't ideal
    http.HandleFunc("/event", Handle)
    go http.Serve(lis, nil)

    // now we set up GRPC
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()

    // this is a GRPC service defined in a proto file and then generated with protoc
    pipelineServer := Server{}

    pipeline.RegisterPipelinesServer(grpcServer, pipelineServer)


    if err := grpcServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %s", err)
    }
}

func Handle(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    log.Infof("handling")
}
```

With the above, sending a `POST` to `localhost:6789/event` will cause the `handling` log line to be emitted.

Comment: Ah, but it looks like graceful shutdown of these two servers isn't possible because the shutdown procedure for both the http server and the grpc server both close the listener. This causes the second-to-shutdown server to fail because the listener closes prematurely.