# Serve REST requests over grpc Server

Tags: go, grpc, gorilla

Came across this link: [Handle REST requests in golang GRPC server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931877/handle-rest-requests-in-golang-grpc-server/73026116#73026116)

I am trying to do something very similar to the above described in the link. But instead of simply logging information, I'm trying to pass the variable obtained from the HTTP request onto the RPC call.

Is this possible? The reason it has to be a RPC call is that the bi-directional streaming is done between the grpc server and client and the data has to be processed back to the user who made the HTTP request.

```
func (s * Server) ConnectAndStream(input *Input, channelStream TestApiService_ConnectAndStreamServer) error {

// TO-DO: This Id has to come from http request
var id int32 = 1234566
// id := a.ConnectAndExchange
log.Println("Id from sam user ", id)

// var id int32 = 1234566   
for i := 1; i <= 2; i++ {
    id += 1
    log.Println("Speed Server is sending data : ", id)
    channelStream.Send(&Input{Id: id})
}


for i := 1; i <= 2; i++ {
    log.Println("now time to receive")
    client_response, err := channelStream.Recv()
    log.Println("Response from samd client : ", client_response.Id)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while receiving from samd : ", err)
    }
}

return nil
```

}

In-line code comment: the id is hardcoded currently and needs to be obtained from the http request.

Update: Following the suggestion here is my attempt, also modified the RPC function to accept an input so I am able to pass it from HTTP request.

```
func main() {
   go runGrpc() // this listens to incoming connections & registers the endpoint for grpc server

   log.Printf("*------ Waiting for requests from SAM users ------*")
   router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
   router.HandleFunc("/exchangeId/{test_id}", ConnectAndExchange).Methods("GET")
   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
```

}

```
func (s * Server) ConnectAndExchange(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    test_id, _ := strconv.Atoi(vars["test_id"])
    log.Println("Test id request from user : ", test_id)

  // Guess: need to enclose this in a go routine since when the 
     test_id is input a stream of response is expected
     res := s.ConnectAndStream(test_id)

    // Process response to user
    // w.Write(res)
    // if f, ok := w.(http.Flusher); ok {
  //    f.Flush()
    // }
```

}

Comment: Yes you can make a gRPC request (streaming or otherwise) in an `http.Handler` (basically just call something similar to your `ConnectAndStream` passing in data from the request). However if the response is a stream you will need to process the results (and push to the `ResponseWriter`) before exiting the handler (this will get more complex if you want to use a single bi-directional call to service multiple HTTP requests). Please have a go at writing the handler and add that to your question. If I've misunderstood then please add detail (I've assumed that you are not using `grpc-gateway`).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, here is my attempt in trying to pass the variable to the rpc call. Adding it to the original question above. Kindly have a look and suggest if this is doable

Comment: In `ConnectAndExchange` you will need to process the streaming response, `s.ConnectAndStream` will return as soon as the connection is up, (see [the docs](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/basics/#server-side-streaming-rpc-1)) and do something with it (I'd guess you want to convert to JSON and write to the `ResponseWriter`).

Comment: Yup, i still have to look into the response writing, but for starters based on the RPC call is it correct when I have called s.ConnectAndStream within the handler function? Is this way correct in calling an RPC method within handler logic?

Comment: I have not used Gorilla Mux so can't really help with that but the basic approach looks OK. Obviously the call to `ConnectAndExchange` is going to have to be `x.ConnectAndExchange` where x is an instance of `Server` (create and connect to gRPC server at startup)..

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand better the flow that you are trying to achieve. Your http handler method can make the outgoing GRPC call to the server and return the response back via the `http.ResponseWriter`.

For simplicity I have used the hello world GRPC example on https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/helloworld

Running the code sample below and hitting `http://localhost:1000/exchangeId/Test` will show the output

```
Starting
*------ Waiting for http requests from users on port 1000 ------*
server listening at 127.0.0.1:1001
Test id request from user :  Test
Server Received: Test
Greeting: Hello Test
```

Code sample:

```
import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure"
    pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var (
    grpcserver = "localhost:1001"
)

func main() {
    log.Print("Starting")
    go StartGrpcServer()

    log.Printf("*------ Waiting for http requests from users on port 1000 ------*")
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/exchangeId/{test_id}", ConnectAndExchange).Methods("GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1000", router))
}

type server struct {
    pb.UnimplementedGreeterServer
}

// SayHello implements helloworld.GreeterServer
func (s *server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    log.Printf("Server Received: %v", in.GetName())
    return &pb.HelloReply{Message: "Hello " + in.GetName()}, nil
}

func StartGrpcServer() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", grpcserver)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
    log.Printf("server listening at %v", lis.Addr())
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}

func ConnectAndExchange(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    test_id := vars["test_id"]
    log.Println("Test id request from user : ", test_id)

    // Set up a connection to the server.
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(grpcserver, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    c := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)

    // Contact the server and print out its response.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    resp, err := c.SayHello(ctx, &pb.HelloRequest{Name: test_id})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not greet: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Greeting: %s", resp.GetMessage())

    w.Write([]byte(resp.GetMessage()))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I was working on a very similar approach earlier (like you described, where the HTTP logic sits on the client and we make an outgoing RPC call to the server), but I think the challenge seems to be having the HTTP handler logic on the server and having it make an outgoing RPC call on the client. Not sure if this is even doable. For the purpose of the application, I am developing the server -> REST interface handles HTTP requests and Client -> is where the processing happens. The setup reason is due to firewall issues. Will soon post the updated code for ref.

Comment: If ^ was confusing, Here is the outline of what we are trying to accomplish      
Server -> Listens to connections on port 9000 & handles HTTP req on port 8000. Client --> Dials in to connect with the server on port 9000                                  HTTP req -> goes to the server, will handle and obtain the params from the req and pass it to the client who should ideally make the RPC call. However, I am able to make an RPC call only on the server since that is where i can obtain HTTP params. RPC calls generated are common for both, but from what I described I think the server processes it.

Comment: ok @Starseamoon thanks for the clarification. I get what you are trying to achieve. Let me try to put a demo in place later on.

Comment: Sure, is grpc gateway the solution you are thinking of?  https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-to-grpc-gateway/ This detailed guide explains how  one could map the rest api endpoint to a rpc service call